# Windows Service Which Checks SSL Certificate Expiry Date and Sends a mail automatically at specified Scheduled Time

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services

I'm new to this i'm working on a code that will check expiry date of SSL certificate and sends a mail to the respected user at regular interval of time or at Scheduled Time. In config settings i made interval as one minute and also made the code to write certain events in a text file called SSLLog.txt. I'm able to run it as local user and it running successfully as service but it is not sending mails to respected user. Please help in this . Below one is the Code for Service1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Net;
using System.Security;

namespace WindowsServiceCS
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            this.WriteToFile("Simple Service started {0}");
            this.ScheduleService();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            this.WriteToFile("Simple Service stopped {0}");
            this.Schedular.Dispose();
        }

        private Timer Schedular;

        public void ScheduleService()
        {
            try
            {
                Schedular = new Timer(new TimerCallback(SchedularCallback));
                string mode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Mode"].ToUpper();
                this.WriteToFile("Simple Service Mode: " + mode + " {0}");

                //Set the Default Time.
                DateTime scheduledTime = DateTime.MinValue;

                if (mode == "DAILY")
                {
                    //Get the Scheduled Time from AppSettings.
                    scheduledTime = DateTime.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ScheduledTime"]);
                    if (DateTime.Now > scheduledTime)
                    {
                        //If Scheduled Time is passed set Schedule for the next day.
                        scheduledTime = scheduledTime.AddDays(1);
                    }
                }

                if (mode.ToUpper() == "INTERVAL")
                {
                    //Get the Interval in Minutes from AppSettings.
                    int intervalMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IntervalMinutes"]);

                    //Set the Scheduled Time by adding the Interval to Current Time.
                    scheduledTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(intervalMinutes);
                    if (DateTime.Now > scheduledTime)
                    {
                        //If Scheduled Time is passed set Schedule for the next Interval.
                        scheduledTime = scheduledTime.AddMinutes(intervalMinutes);
                    }
                }

                TimeSpan timeSpan = scheduledTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
                string schedule = string.Format("{0} day(s) {1} hour(s) {2} minute(s) {3} seconds(s)", timeSpan.Days, timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds);

                this.WriteToFile("Simple Service scheduled to run after: " + schedule + " {0}");

                //Get the difference in Minutes between the Scheduled and Current Time.
                int dueTime = Convert.ToInt32(timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds);

                //Change the Timer's Due Time.
                Schedular.Change(dueTime, Timeout.Infinite);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToFile("Simple Service Error on: {0} " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);

                //Stop the Windows Service.
                using (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController serviceController = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("SimpleService"))
                {
                    serviceController.Stop();
                }
            }
        }

        private void SchedularCallback(object e)
        {
            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ServerCertificateValidationCallback;

                var request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.co.in");

                var response = request.GetResponse();
                WriteToFile("Check Completed");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToFile("The Exception caused is " + ex);
            }
            this.WriteToFile("Simple Service Log: {0}");
            this.ScheduleService();
        }
        private bool ServerCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            try
            {
                WriteToFile("Certificate expires on " + certificate.GetExpirationDateString());
                string name = "Tillapudi Venkata Sundeep";
                string email = "xxxxxxxx1@gmail.com";
                WriteToFile("Trying to send email to: " + name + " " + email);
                System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
                client.Port = 587;
                client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Timeout = 10000;
                client.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxxx");
                System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mm = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("xxxxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxx1@gmail.com", "Test Mail Sent From Visual Studio", "Hey buddy How are you doing");
                mm.BodyEncoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
                mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = System.Net.Mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
                WriteToFile("Mail Sent");
                client.Send(mm);
                WriteToFile("Mail Sent");
            }
           catch(Exception exce)
            {
                WriteToFile("The Execption caused in the mail" +exce);
            }
            return true;
        }


        private void WriteToFile(string text)
        {
            string path = "C:\\SSlLog.txt";
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(string.Format(text, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")));
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```